# Can I convert a sensor_msgs::Pointcloud to pcl::pointcloud

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, pcl

Can I convert **sensor_msgs::Pointcloud** to **pcl::pointcloud** directly or I need to convert **sensor_msgs::Pointcloud** to **sensor_msgs::Pointcloud2** before converting it to **pcl::pointcloud**?

Comment: Just to make sure: do you really mean [sensor_msgs/PointCloud](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html)? I didn't think anyone is still using that, I thought everyone is using sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.

Comment: yes sesor_msgs/PointCloud. I am using the code [here](https://github.com/Vidicon/2dscantoPointcloud/blob/master/src/lidar_transform.cpp). I need to convert **senosr/pointcloud** into pcl::pointcloud so I can add the passthrough filter

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood it PCL can only work with sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 directly. [ros_pcl](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/ros2/pcl_ros/include/pcl_ros/point_cloud.hpp).

U can use a converter as the middle-man between your pcl node and your publisher node. [How to convert sensor_msgs::pointcloud to sensor_msgs::pointcloud2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807952/how-to-convert-sensor-msgspointcloud-to-sensor-msgspointcloud2)

or

If possible use sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
Take a look at: [laser-scan-multi-merger](https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools/blob/ros1-master/src/laserscan_multi_merger.cpp) it can be used to convert only one laser-scan topic aswell and directly converts it to PointCloud2.
The pass through filter can be done on the pcl::PointCloud side aswell no?

Comment: pls accept this as an answer if you think it solved your problem. If not indicate what is missing/unclear
Thanks in advance