# How to convert sensor_msgs::pointcloud to sensor_msgs::pointcloud2

Tags: ros, pcl

I am using the code [here][1] which have **sensor_msgs::pointcloud**. Can someone help me how to convert it to **sensor_msgs::pointcloud2**
[1]: https://github.com/Vidicon/2dscantoPointcloud/blob/master/src/lidar_transform.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method `convertPointCloudToPointCloud2` from [point_cloud_conversion.hpp](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/sensor_msgs/include/sensor_msgs/point_cloud_conversion.hpp)

Answer (score 0):

This code is quite old and you shouldn't really be using PointCloud messages now. That being said, you can run the [pointcloud_converter node](https://github.com/pal-robotics-forks/point_cloud_converter/blob/hydro-devel/src/converter.cpp) to get your message out as a PointCloud2. Take this launch file for example:

```
<launch>
    </node name="pointcloud_converter" type="point_cloud_converter" pkg="point_cloud_converter">
        <remap from="points_in" to="/your_topic" />
        <remap from="points_out" to="/your_output_topic" />
    </node>
</launch>
```